# C++ Using "putchar" to output a word in Binary

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation

My function:

```
void output(int word)
{   
      file << putchar((word >> 24) & 0xff);
      file << putchar((word >> 16) & 0xff);
      file << putchar((word >> 8) & 0xff);
      file << putchar(word & 0xff);
}
```

where "file" uses fstream to output the binary from putchar to a file called "binary.bin".
When "word" is 1, the binary representation of the binary.bin is 00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001.

It should've been 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001. (Note: a word is 32 bits)

00110000 00110000 00110000 00110001 is the ascii representation of 0001 (30 30 30 31).

What went wrong?

Comment: try using `unsigned int word` out there instead and tell me what you get.

Comment: The binary output stayed the same.

Comment: how do you open the file for writing?

Comment: **Global variable:**  ofstream file; 
**In main:** file.open("binary.bin"); **Used by function and then:** file.close();

Comment: Use `file.open("binary.bin",ios::binary);` there.

Comment: Same output. Is "putchar" the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `operator<<`.  The stream insertion operator is designed to convert it's input to text format and pass the formatted text to the stream.

```
  file << putchar((word >> 24) & 0xff);
       ^^----> this is the problem.
```

You will need to use a stream method that doesn't perform translations, such as `std::ostream::put` or `std::ostream::write`.

**Also, be aware that the `putchar` function writes its argument to the console and returns the argument if successful.**
See [explanation of putchar.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/putchar)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is trying to use text mode functions to write in binary. You should use `file::put(char)` instead. Like that:

```
void output(int word)
{   
    file.put(word >> 24);
    file.put(word >> 16);
    file.put(word >> 8);
    file.put(word);
}
```

As `file.put` takes only `char`, you do not need to and the result with 0xff, so I left it out.

Also, I did not understand why are you using `putchar()`. It prints only to the console, not to files.