# How to write binary into a file using std::ostream::put?

Tags: c++, file-io, stl, ostream

I'm trying to implement TGA-Compression using run-length-encoding algorithm. One problem that I'm having is outputting the bytes, that give information how many times a color is repeated, into a file. I have already read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put but it didn't help me much.

```
void encode(const TGAImage& inputImage, std::ostream& os){
        TGAImageHeader header = inputImage.getHeader();
        header.setCompressed();
        os << header;

        std::vector<ARGB32> data = inputImage.getData();
        //it1 where it starts repeating and it2 where it ends, both are iterators, repeat if the color repeats
        auto lambda = [&](const auto& it1, const auto& it2, const bool& repeat){
            auto dist = std::distance(it1, it2);
            if(dist > 0 || repeat){
                os.put(dist);
                os << *it1;
        };   

        auto i = data.begin();
        while(i != data.end()){
            auto start = std::adjacent_find(i, data.end(),
                [&](const ARGB32& a, const ARGB32& b){return a == b;});

            auto end = std::find_if(start, data.end(),
                [&](const auto& a){ return a != *start; });

            lambda(start, end, start != end);
            i = end;
        }
    }
```

when i try os.put(dist) i get the following warning:

```
src/runlengthencoding.cpp:23:24: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type’ {aka ‘char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   23 |                 os.put(dist);
      |                        ^~~~
```

The only thing that i could find was this thread: [C++ Using "putchar" to output a word in Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303013/c-using-putchar-to-output-a-word-in-binary) and i tried doing it the way the second comments suggests but i get a warnings as well and i don't get how `os.put(dist >> 24);` works.

```
src/runlengthencoding.cpp:42:44:   required from here
src/runlengthencoding.cpp:20:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type’ {aka ‘char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   20 |                 os.put(dist >> 24);
      |                        ~~~~~^~~~~

src/runlengthencoding.cpp:21:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type’ {aka ‘char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   21 |                 os.put(dist >> 16);
      |                        ~~~~~^~~~~

src/runlengthencoding.cpp:22:29: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type’ {aka ‘char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   22 |                 os.put(dist >> 8);
      |                        ~~~~~^~~~

src/runlengthencoding.cpp:23:24: warning: conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::char_type’ {aka ‘char’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   23 |                 os.put(dist);
      |                        ^~~~
```

Comment: Neither of your code samples (nor frankly any of the answers) are following the TGA spec. You should realise that `put` writes a **byte**. You should realise that TGA limits run lengths to 128 bytes. You should realise that when you write a run length you subtract one from the length and (in your case because you are outputting a run of the same pixel) set the high bit to one. Your code isn't doing any of these things.

Comment: Correction - the above comment should say TGA limits run lengths to 128 pixels, not 128  bytes.

Comment: @john i do realize the following things: 1) ```put``` writes a byte, TGA limits run lengths to 128 pixels. but i'm having a hard time grasping the other things you mentioned and how can i implement those.

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1):

`ostream::put()` takes a single `char`, but you are giving it a `long int` instead, which is larger than a `char`. So the compiler is warning you that the value of the integer is being truncated, thus it will lose precision for any value greater than `CHAR_MAX` (which, on most systems where `char` is 8 bits, is 127 if `char` is signed, or 255 if unsigned).

Which is fine in the bit-shifting case, as it is `put()`'ing the individual bytes of the integer, which each fit within a `char`:

- `dist >> 24` is shifting the value of bits 24..31 (the 4th highest byte) into bits 0..7 (the lowest byte). The result is then passed to `put()`, truncating it to 8 bits when converted to `char`.
- `dist >> 16` is shifting bits 16..23 (the 3rd highest byte) into bits 0..7.
- `dist >> 8` is shifting bits 8..15 (the 2nd highest byte) into bits 0..7.
- passing `dist` as-is does not shift anything, so bits 0..7 already contain the value of the 1st highest byte, aka the lowest byte.

Otherwise, you can use `ostream::write()` instead:

```
os.write((char*)&dist, sizeof(dist));
```

Just be aware that this approach is affected by the size and endian (byte order) of the integer.  The bit-shifting approach is not affected by that.

Comment: how does the 2nd case work? what does dist >> 24, 16, 8 actually do? i understand bit shifting but why 24, 16, 8. can you link any material or links where i can read about that?

Comment: @yad0 This code does not follow the TGA spec. If would be fine if you were trying to solve a different problem but it is not right for you.

Comment: @john but how does that work though? can you point to any useful material i can read?

Comment: @yad0 You've lost me, are you still referring to the bit shifting code?

Comment: @yad0 if you really understood bit shifting, and what bytes are, and how integers are laid out in memory, then you wouldn't need to ask about those numbers. But ok, I've updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going off of https://www.fileformat.info/format/tga/egff.htm (search for "run-length encoding") as I'm not familiar with the TGA format. It says that it expects a single byte for the run length, with a max value of 127. So, you need to make sure you're limiting your runs to 127. Then, since you know that your value is small enough to fit in a byte, you can use `static_cast< char >( dist )` to tell the compiler you're not worried about the conversion.

That page also says that "The high bit of the pixel count value is always set to 1 to indicate that this is a run-length encoded packet." To set the high bit of the byte, you can use a binary "or" with 0x80 (a byte value with only the high bit set): `static_cast< char >( dist ) | 0x80`. The compiler might complain that 0x80 is too big to fit in a *signed* char, because 0x80 = 128 and signed chars hold numbers from -128 to 127. If it does complain, you can force it with `static_cast< char >( 0x80 )`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that given two iterators `it1` and `it2` writes a TGA run-length encoded sequence of identical pixels.

```
size_t dist = std::distance(it1, it2);
while (dist > 0)
{
    size_t length = std::min(dist, 128); // run lengths are limited to 128
    uint8_t byte = (uint8_t)length;
    --byte;         // subtract one from length
    byte |= 128;    // and set the high bit
    os.put(byte);   // output length byte
    os << *it1;     // output pixel
    dist -= length; // adjust distance left to output
}
```